# Цель: Вывести массив в обратном порядке JAVA

Tags: java, массивы

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arrey2[] = new int [10];

        arrey2[0] = 111;
        arrey2[1] = 222;
        arrey2[2] = 333;
        arrey2[3] = 444;
        arrey2[4] = 555;
        arrey2[5] = 666;
        arrey2[6] = 777;
        arrey2[7] = 757;
        arrey2[8] = 777;
        arrey2[9] = 888;

        int length1 = arrey2.length;



        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(arrey2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот сам код, выводит в обычном порядке

Comment: `i = 9; i >= 0; i--`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
   System.out.println(arrey2[i]);
}
```